# Sqlalchemy ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'None'

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to run the following code but I got a sqlalchemy invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'None' error.

```
import os
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv('.env')

#MOben DB
moben_db_creds = {
    'host' : os.getenv('POSTGRES_MOBEN_HOST'),
    'port' : os.getenv('POSTGRES_MOBEN_PORT'),
    'user' : os.getenv('POSTGRES_MOBEN_USER'),
    'password' : os.getenv('POSTGRES_MOBEN_DBPASS'),
    'name' : os.getenv('POSTGRES_MOBEN_DBNAME'),
    'type' : os.getenv('POSTGRES_MOBEN_DBTYPE')
}

sqlalchemy_db_uri_conn = f"{moben_db_creds['type']}://{moben_db_creds['user']}:{moben_db_creds['password']}@{moben_db_creds['host']}:{moben_db_creds['port']}/{moben_db_creds['name']}"

# DEFINE THE ENGINE (CONNECTION OBJECT)
engine = create_engine(sqlalchemy_db_uri_conn)

# CREATE A SESSION OBJECT TO INITIATE QUERY IN DATABASE
session = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

base = declarative_base()

def get_db():
    db = session()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()
```

As i am quite new to this orm, unable to identify the solution to this error.

please follow below Traceback for more detail
Traceback: ==============================================================

```
(env_ucom_csb) PS C:\Users\e008329\Downloads\project_zone\ucom-csb-payload-publisher> uvicorn main:app --reload
INFO:     Will watch for changes in these directories: ['C:\\Users\\e008329\\Downloads\\project_zone\\ucom-csb-payload-publisher']
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     Started reloader process [27160] using WatchFiles
Process SpawnProcess-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\e008329\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap       
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\e008329\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "c:\users\e008329\downloads\project_zone\env_ucom_csb\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\_subprocess.py", line 76, in subprocess_started
    target(sockets=sockets)
  File "c:\users\e008329\downloads\project_zone\env_ucom_csb\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\server.py", line 60, in run
    return asyncio.run(self.serve(sockets=sockets))
  File "C:\Users\e008329\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "C:\Users\e008329\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete   
    return future.result()
  File "c:\users\e008329\downloads\project_zone\env_ucom_csb\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\server.py", line 67, in serve
    config.load()
  File "c:\users\e008329\downloads\project_zone\env_ucom_csb\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\config.py", line 477, in load
    self.loaded_app = import_from_string(self.app)
  File "c:\users\e008329\downloads\project_zone\env_ucom_csb\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\importer.py", line 21, in import_from_string
    module = importlib.import_module(module_str)
  File "C:\Users\e008329\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\e008329\Downloads\project_zone\ucom-csb-payload-publisher\.\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from publish_ucom_csb import publish_uci_all
  File "C:\Users\e008329\Downloads\project_zone\ucom-csb-payload-publisher\.\publish_ucom_csb.py", line 2, in <module>
    from models.v_payload_ucom_csb import VPayloadUCOMCsb
  File "C:\Users\e008329\Downloads\project_zone\ucom-csb-payload-publisher\.\models\v_payload_ucom_csb.py", line 2, in <module>    from config.database import base
  File "C:\Users\e008329\Downloads\project_zone\ucom-csb-payload-publisher\.\config\database.py", line 31, in <module>
    engine = create_engine(sqlalchemy_db_uri_conn)
  File "<string>", line 2, in create_engine
  File "c:\users\e008329\downloads\project_zone\env_ucom_csb\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\deprecations.py", line 277, in warned
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]
  File "c:\users\e008329\downloads\project_zone\env_ucom_csb\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\create.py", line 552, in create_engine
    u = _url.make_url(url)
  File "c:\users\e008329\downloads\project_zone\env_ucom_csb\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\url.py", line 838, in make_url    return _parse_url(name_or_url)
  File "c:\users\e008329\downloads\project_zone\env_ucom_csb\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\url.py", line 893, in _parse_url
    components["port"] = int(components["port"])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'None'
```

Comment: Where exactly? Pleas post the whole traceback.

Comment: At a guess, your environment variable for the port is not set or misspelt.

Comment: Values in moben_db_creds are probably set to none

Comment: +1 to "post the whole traceback", we can help you learn how to make sense of it which is an essential skill

Comment: Thanks for the response guys, I have added whole traceback.

Comment: The traceback demonstrates that you are passing `None` for the port. You need to check your environment variables.

Comment: POSTGRES_MOBEN_HOST='127.0.0.1'
POSTGRES_MOBEN_PORT=54320
POSTGRES_MOBEN_USER='user'
POSTGRES_MOBEN_DBPASS='password'
POSTGRES_MOBEN_DBNAME='dbname'
POSTGRES_MOBEN_DBTYPE='postgresql'

env file content

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a default port value when you are using the `os.getenv` (see https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getenv)
e.g.

```py
DEFAULT_PORT_VALUE =  9999
moben_db_creds = {
    'host' : os.getenv('POSTGRES_MOBEN_HOST'),
    'port' : os.getenv('POSTGRES_MOBEN_PORT', DEFAULT_PORT_VALUE),
     ...
     }
```

Right now it seems you are passing `None` in the line referenced by the traceback:

```py
    components["port"] = int(components["port"])
```

The other option would be to use `get` instead of `[]` syntax to get the value from the components dict.

```py
    components["port"] = int(components.get("port", DEFAULT_PORT_VALUE))
```

Btw. it's necessarily about the env file **contents** it might be about its **location** (or the command you are using to run the script / start the server). Print or log the values after you get them from the env file and see if they are being read correctly.

Comment: I have passed values in these format inside env file

POSTGRES_MOBEN_HOST='127.0.0.1'
POSTGRES_MOBEN_PORT=54320
POSTGRES_MOBEN_USER='user'
POSTGRES_MOBEN_DBPASS='password'
POSTGRES_MOBEN_DBNAME='dbname'
POSTGRES_MOBEN_DBTYPE='postgresql'

Comment: Again it's not necessarily about the env file contents it's whether it's being read in a correct way. Print or log what the read values are to ensure that.